# Autosort on edit not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a list (Google sheet) of 4 team games we organize and a list of participants. I got something to work that auto sorts – but it only works on the first column. Here's the script

```html
/**
 * Automatically sorts the 1st column (not the header row) Descending.
 */
function onEdit(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sh.getActiveRange().getColumnIndex();

  if(editedCell == 2) { 
    var range = sh.getRange("A2:B100");
    range.sort({column: 2, ascending: false });
  }
}
```

I've [linked my test goog sheet here...its editable](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cfgYJ91h6g6bLqrI5uuUoUYgqcyM0WoktirxBjxVbN0/edit?usp=sharing).

I need something that can do a simple AutoSort on all 8 columns (4 datasets of 2 cols each) as follows:

These are 4 separate teams (and to separate them, I’ve colored them as such- they have nothing related to each other- so only Col A & B are related, then Col C & D are related, likewise) so Col A & B is 1st game team; Col C & D is 2nd game team (totally separate from Game 1) and Col E & F is 3rd game team (totally separate from Game1 & 2)

All that sheet needs to Autosort is:
Anytime an edit is made it shd. first sort Descending on Col A, then Ascending Col B; likewise Descending on Col C, then Ascending Col D; likewise Descending on Col E, then Ascending Col F; likewise Descending on Col G, then Ascending Col H
And it shd. ignore any blank cells...

All 4 teams are placed together only for formatting and printing purposes but need to be sorted separately.

Comment: please describe us what is not working. Are you sure your script is running correctly and did not crash? Is another column being sorted?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you look at documentation for `Range#sort()`? It takes as an argument an **array** of sort objects. Your code passes only a single object...

Answer (score 1):

## Sort Columns in Pairs

This might be a little easier if you ever want to change the number columns. Just change them and make sure you have an even number.  They will sort on the even numbered columns and the column to the left.

```
function onEdit(e){
  sortNColumns(e);
}

function sortNColumns(e){
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var col=e.range.getColumn();
  if(col<=sh.getLastColumn() && col%2==0){//less than or equal to the last column and even.  You could just go with col%2==0 if you want it works too
    sh.getRange(2,col-1,sh.getLastRow()-1,2).sort({column:col,ascending:false});
  }
}
```

Comment: No..I checkd it..not working and also it seems you only referred 1& 2 cols? Pls. recheck..its doing nothing

Comment: How are you executing this function.  It can't be run from the editor.  You have to make a change to the spreadsheet to generate an onEdit event.  I checked it.  It does work.

Comment: @sa I went to your spreadsheet and got the code working as you desire...I think.

Comment: thanks for your time Cooper. Someone else suggested some changes and that makes it work when I add checkboxes even.